# New paragraph and enumerate - should I keep an indent?

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs

I am wondering which scenario is correct in terms of typesetting.

There is one paragraph and then I have a sentence which is followed by enumerated list. Should I keep the indentation or ignore it? Is it a good idea to add a new line in such situation?

Version 1
[image]

Version 2
[image]

In my humble opinion the second one looks better but I am not sure if this approach is suitable.

Comment: I think it's  a semantic problem. However, for the 1st kind of solution, you should try loading `enumitem` and `\begin{enumerate}[wide=\parindent]` (maybe `wide` alone gives the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Bernard's suggestion to use the `enumitem` package. It easily lets you tweak the horizontal and vertical spaces around all of the standard list environments just so, and also lets you define special-purpose custom list formats.

An example of how this can be applied in your case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[enumerate,itemize]{ % apply settings globally 
    wide=\parindent,
    topsep=3pt,
    partopsep=0pt,
    parsep=0pt,
    itemsep=2pt
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\smallskip % depending on your list settings, omit, or try \medskip or \bigskip 

Blah, blah, blah, blah

\begin{enumerate}

\item One

\item Two 

\item Three

\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]